# Fixing dashboards on Team Foundation SharePoint portal

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, integration

The project Dashboards will not display on my SharePoint Team Project portal, as below:
[image: No dashboards]

However, project data *should* be available.  Excel Reports *do* work, and I can browse the cube through SSMS.  I checked the warehouse web service, and it also reports everything is fine and ready:
[image: Warehouse web service GetProcessingStatus]

Project Work Items, Recent Builds, and Recent Checkins web parts are all also working fine. Any thoughts on the final piece I'm missing to get dashboards to show up?

Edit: More confusing behavior; When I click Edit Page, the dashboard web parts *do* show up.  Each pops up the confirmation asking if I want to load external queries, but after I click yes for each, it loads up fine and shows the data.

Another Edit: It appears the web parts are starting Minimized. I can click the context menu and select Restore, and then the content will show, as pictured below.  However, I still have the questions why are the starting minimized and what is with the inaccurate error message in red?
[image: Web parts starting minimized]